# Call get_option() in other file than plugin's main file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin where I need to use the `get_option()` in other file than the plugin's main file.

My plugin file structure is like this:

```
/my-plugin
|
|__ my-plugin.php            // In this file I can call get_option()
|__ dynamic-stylesheet.php   // Here I want to use get_option()
```

And lets say I have registered a setting upon plugin activation `register_setting( 'my_plugin', 'my_plugin_settings');`

If I call `get_option('my_plugin_settings');` in **my-plugin.php** it works really well but if I call the same function in **dynamic-stylesheet.php** it shows function undefined error.

I have **dynamic-stylesheet.php** to work as style sheet where I can put some PHP variable and in **my-plugin.php** I have called this file as this so it can be added as my style sheet in theme's **header.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles');

function my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin-style', plugins_url( "dynamic-stylesheet.php", __FILE__ ));
}
```

I have researched and found a way to include `wp-load.php` in order it to work. But I don't think its a good practice...

Can anyone tell me a better way to do that?

Comment: how did you register plugin ? please add the code of my-plugin.php

Comment: Are you talking about registering plugin settings?

Comment: yes and then you need to include dynamic-stylesheet.php in main file

Comment: Sure... let me edit my question

Comment: Did you put some code in my-plugin.php like `require_once(plugin_dir(__file__).'/dynamic-stylesheet.php');`

Comment: @Benoti Have updated my question again... But I think the question is clear that I want to use the [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) in the file other than the main plugin file... Because it works fine in the main file

Comment: wp_enqueue_scripts is made to enqueue css file and js file not php file, use my code instead of yours and it will work.

Comment: @Benoti Actually it works when you set Content-Type: text/css... I have made it work ... Anyway its not my real question ... Just tell if you know that How can I call `get_option()` in any other file?

Comment: You can in every php file that is include or require by the main plugin file. You can not include php files with add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles'); . That's why get_option don't work.

Comment: That's explain well...